# Unable to see the plugin compiled in the custom wireshark run?

Tags: wireshark-dissector

I am following the foo example given in the wireshark documentation.
I am able to build the foo code plugin. I am using wireshark 3.0.1 version. In the workroot folder, I have updated the target - PLUGIN_SRC_DIRS - plugins/epan/foo just before gryphon.

I can see that my code builds because I got some compilation error which I was able to fix it.

My foo code lives inside the plugins/epan folder.
I am running custom wireshark -  sudo ./run/wireshark
There is a surprise here that I can't see even gryphon protocol field in the running wireshark. So in order to test this, I am typing foo or gryphon in that display filter and it turns red and it say foo is neither a protocol nor a protocol field. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to build it. The build goes fine.

Here is packet-foo.c

```
#include "config.h"
#include <epan/packet.h>
#include "packet-foo.h"


static int proto_foo = -1;

static int dissect_foo(tvbuff_t *tvb, packet_info *pinfo, proto_tree *tree _U_, void *data _U_);


void
proto_register_foo(void)
{
    proto_foo = proto_register_protocol (
        "FOO Protocol", /* name       */
        "FOO",      /* short name */
        "foo"       /* abbrev     */
        );
}

void
proto_reg_handoff_foo(void)
{
    static dissector_handle_t foo_handle;

    foo_handle = create_dissector_handle(dissect_foo, proto_foo);
    dissector_add_uint("udp.port", FOO_PORT, foo_handle);
}

static int
dissect_foo(tvbuff_t *tvb, packet_info *pinfo, proto_tree *tree _U_, void *data _U_)
{
    col_set_str(pinfo->cinfo, COL_PROTOCOL, "FOO");
    /* Clear out stuff in the info column */
    col_clear(pinfo->cinfo,COL_INFO);

    return tvb_captured_length(tvb);
}
```

Here is the packet-foo.h

```
#define FOO_PORT 1234
```

The CMakeLists.txt is here, this is actually a copy of gryphon.
So, I am wondering if gryphon wasn't recognised that means foo won't be recognised too. So, this file might be a source of problem.

```
include(WiresharkPlugin)

# Plugin name and version info (major minor micro extra)
set_module_info(foo 0 0 4 0)

set(DISSECTOR_SRC
    packet-foo.c
)

set(PLUGIN_FILES
    plugin.c
    ${DISSECTOR_SRC}
)

set_source_files_properties(
    ${PLUGIN_FILES}
    PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_FLAGS "${WERROR_COMMON_FLAGS}"
)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

register_plugin_files(plugin.c
    plugin
    ${DISSECTOR_SRC}
)

add_plugin_library(foo epan)

target_link_libraries(foo epan)

install_plugin(foo epan)

file(GLOB DISSECTOR_HEADERS RELATIVE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" "*.h")
CHECKAPI(
    NAME
      foo
    SWITCHES
      -g abort -g termoutput -build
    SOURCES
      ${DISSECTOR_SRC}
      ${DISSECTOR_HEADERS}
)
```

[image: Plugin Folder]

Comment: Can you attach the screen shot of about wireshark and then press plugins tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merely changing the plugin isn't sufficient.
You need to modify the top make file so that foo is actually installed.

vim CMakeListsCustom.txt.example

Firstly, uncomment - line number 16

```
 plugins/epan/foo
```

Since your foo lives inside plugins/epan/foo

Now, rename this example to

## `mv CMakeListsCustom.txt.example CMakeListsCustom.txt`

```
vim CMakeLists.txt
```

Insert a line number around 1408-
plugins/epan/foo

After that, do `make` 
and then `sudo make install`

Here is the working copy -

https://github.com/joshis1/WiresharkDissectorFoo